# WordPress - Remove Ancestor Listing from this

Tags: wordpress

I took this code directly & unedited from the WordPress Codex and it essentially lists the children of the current page. However, I would like to remove the listing of the parent / ancestor. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<?php
//if the post has a parent
if($post->post_parent){
  //collect ancestor pages
  $relations = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
  //get child pages
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = $post->ID AND post_type='page'" );
  if ($result){
    foreach($result as $pageID){
      array_push($relations, $pageID->ID);
    }
  }
  //add current post to pages
  array_push($relations, $post->ID);
  //get comma delimited list of children and parents and self
  $relations_string = implode(",",$relations);
  //use include to list only the collected pages. 
  $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&include=".$relations_string);
}else{
  // display only main level and children
  $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=1&child_of=".$post->ID);
}

if ($sidelinks) { ?>
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php //links in <li> tags
    echo $sidelinks; ?>
  </ul>         
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need to complicate the problem. If you want to get children of current post, just check if it has children and if yes, show them. You need to adjust to your needs of course. But is just shows how to get them.

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
else
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
<ul>
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This link is useful for what you want to do:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: This is perfect and works exactly as I wanted. Thank you Nimle for the help :)

Comment: Hi Nimle, how can I list only the immediate tier of children and not multiple tiers? Thx

Comment: You can add other parameters to filter: Depth is the probably the one you want. For example, depth=1
    
  wp_list_pages("depth=1&title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");

Or if you want to see but not print, you can check the child's parent id to see if it equals to the current post id. If not, that means it is not a direct child.

Comment: Thanks again Nimle. I realized it wasn't proper etiquette to ask multiple questions under a single thread. I've posted a variation of the above question here. If you have a chance to offer some advice, it'd be appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070438/wordpress-listing-only-1-tier-of-children