# WordPress - listing only 1 tier of children

Tags: wordpress

Using the code below, how can I display only the immediate set of children associated with the current page and not the children's children or the other parents on the tier of that page. I assume that the depth parameter is a part of the solution however, I'm unsure as to how to best implement it. Also, does the depth refer to the hierarchy in an absolute or relative fashion. I'd like for it to show only 1 level of depth relative to the page that is selected.

Thank you much for the help and if I can offer any clarification, please let me know.

```
 <?php
    if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: How about using `get_pages('child_of=' . get_the_ID() .'&hierarchical=0&parent=' . get_the_ID());` instead? You can loop the array which is returned by this code to display all the info.

Comment: Hey Harsh8888, thx for the reply. I tried the above code and it didn't appear to work. I ended up moving forward with a conditional statement that says (if grandchildren) then (show siblings).

Answer (score 2):

depth is used in this way:

```
wp_list_pages("depth=1&title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
```

What happens if you use this one?

from documentation:

depth: 
(integer) This parameter controls how many levels in the hierarchy of pages are to be included in the list generated by wp_list_pages. The default value is 0 (display all pages, including all sub-pages).

0 (default) Displays pages at any depth and arranges them hierarchically in nested lists

-1 Displays pages at any depth and arranges them in a single, flat list

1 Displays top-level Pages only

2, 3 … Displays Pages to the given depth

.

Comment: Hey Nimle, Thank you again for advice and explanation. This works great. However, I currently have 3 tiers (parent, child, and sub child). I'd like the sub child pages (final tier) to show their siblings. Currently, when a user visits a sub page, there are no options that show. Any help is most appreciated

Comment: Sub child pages also have their children and you want to show them? If the current one is sub-page then depth 1 will show its children, so it is ok. But if you want to show children, grandchildren etc all, then use depth=-1. Is it what you want? Post an url if you want.

Comment: My apologies. I should have been clearer. The sub child pages have no children and so for these pages, I'd like them to show their siblings.

Comment: To show siblings, you get parent of the current one and then list pages for the id of the parent. 
`wp_list_pages("depth=1&title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); `
This will work for you. 
That's why I had put two lines of wp_list_pages in my answer to your original post that you check if post has a parent, then show children. if no parent, then show siblings. You used that code in this post question. See two lines? that'w why we check post_parent

Comment: Thx for the response. I see what you're saying about the "if" statements. However, in this case, the sub children (grandchildren) have parents and so the code has the page attempting to pull its children. Since these grandchildren have no children, there would be no options to display. After doing some more digging, I found a conditional that essentially says (if grandchildren) then display siblings. This worked great and I adapted it to your code. Thanks again for all the help and assistance :)

Comment: Cool, by the way if you want to remove current post from siblings, you can exclude by id:
`wp_list_pages("depth=1&title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&exclude=".$post->ID);`